# Eclipse how to disable debug mode

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging

I've just installed Eclipse for PHP developper and I create a little project (hosted on wamp).
when I navigate on browser on my website (http://localhost/workspace/monprojet/), Eclipse debugger start on Eclipse. 
I would like test my site without debug mode. How can i do ?

Thks

Comment: You may find these links useful [enabling and disabling breakpoints](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-enable_disable_breakpoints.htm) and [Running and Debugging](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-enable_disable_breakpoints.htm)

Answer (score 5):

Debugger start, because xdebug starts on your server. You have couple options:

1. Disable JIT in eclipse xdebug settings (Preferences => PHP => Debug => Debuggers)
2. Remove xdebug cookie manually from browser
3. Use extensions like "The easiest XDebug" to control xdebug cookies